# Push messages with Azure Service Bus relayed messages

Tags: c#, azure

I have an application receiving a continuous stream of data that has to be forwarded to one or more other parties. Those other parties are not a part of my enterprise so using relayed messages in Azure Service Bus seemed a good idea. Furthermore, in a tutorial on PluralSight it is stated that the same relayed message can be multicasted to up to 20 receivers. However, the only tutorials I can find on multicast concerns queues / topics, but that requires the other parties to be pulling messages in, which is not what I want. Can anyone know of a tutorial fitting my description?

What I hope to figure out is the following: Do I, the holder of the data that has to be broadcast, define a service? Or do the other parties define a service that I can send a message to? It's possible that I'm on the wrong track with relayed messages in Azure Service Bus, if there is a better alternative then I would be keen to learn more of it.

Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Bus relaying allows you to publish (or receive) messages to Service Bus from an on-premise environment by way of WCF services.  Regardless of whether this is the right solution in any bus-orientated environment your clients would need to subscribe in order to receive messages from the bus so you'd need to provide hooks for them - either via the Service Bus APIs directly (and they write custom code) or through exposing a web API or similar to allow them to read messages.